# configure: error: vpx_codec.h not found while installing php-gd bundled extension

Tags: 14.04, server, php, lamp, codecs

While [installing php-gd bundled extension to make imageantialias() function work without re-compiling php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35560150/php-gd-bundled-extension-without-recompiling-php-solution), `./configure` script have thrown following error:

```
sudo ./configure --with-php-config=/usr/bin/php-config --with-gd --with-freetype-dir=shared,/usr --with-vpx-dir=shared,/usr --with-jpeg-dir=shared,/usr --with-xpm-dir=shared,/usr/X11R6 

checking for grep that handles long lines and -e... /bin/grep
checking for egrep... /bin/grep -E
...
configure: error: vpx_codec.h not found.
```

What is the way to run ./configure script without having `configure: error: vpx_codec.h not found.` ? My server is Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS, PHP version 5.5.9 and php-gd was installed without compiling from source, but installed via `apt-get install php php-gd`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The file `vpx_codec.h` belongs to a package called `libvpx-dev`

To fix the error, install it by running `sudo apt-get install libvpx-dev` command.
And then run `./configure` command with the same command arguments then you'll see following result:

`checking for vpx_codec_destroy in -lvpx... yes`